# Can't import jQuery in Angular with stackblitz.com

Tags: jquery, angular

I am trying to setup an Angular project on stackblitz.com using signalR.  When I try to import signalR I get an error saying I must reference jQuery first.  All of the solutions I have read seem to boil down to the following

1. Add dependency to jquery
2. Add `"./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"` to `Angular.json` in `script[]` tag
3. Add `"jquery"` to to `types[]` tag in `tsconfig.app.json` and `tsconfig.spec.json`

When i do this it shows `$` is not defined however if I download copy the `src` dir and build local it works fine and resolves `jquery`.  Is there something I'm missing on stackblitz  I had to make new `tsconfig.spec.json` and `tsconfig.app.json` because they were not visible when I created the project

Comment: You don't need jquery for SignalR

Comment: I believe I do. It appears aspnet/SignalR is only compatible with .Net core. I’m trying to use standard .Net

Comment: I am trying to self host using OWIN. Right now I’m using a console app but will migrate to a service eventually. I can’t migrate to .Net core because of other dependencies.

Comment: Okey you use normal signalr library which requires jquery

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-welnxa

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-twuszr